# Can you have multiple methods of filtering a Jquery Mobile Listview

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, filtering

I have a JQM listview that is being populated with user data similar to what you would see in your address book. I want my users to be able to filter the list in multiple ways.

What I mean by this is that I want the regular search field that appears with a filterable listview but also a dropdown menu that will allow me to quickly filter the list by some sort of data type.

For instance, I want to only show the people with email addresses or people with profile pictures and then use the search field to narrow down that filtered list even more.

Just to clarify, I do not want the item selected on the drop down list to appear in the search field. They should be two separate actions that apply to the same listview.

Is something like this possible?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!